# Feed column data from one table into another

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have a "bindings" table like this:

```
binding_id,record_id,game_id,layout_id,normal_action
71,NULL,3,1,Vorpal\nBlade
72,NULL,3,1,Cards
73,NULL,3,1,Mallet
129,NULL,4,1,Fist
130,NULL,4,1,Pistol
131,NULL,4,1,Shotgun
209,NULL,5,1,"Quick\nSlot 1"
210,NULL,5,1,"Quick\nSlot 2"
211,NULL,5,1,"Quick\nSlot 3"
297,NULL,6,1,Select\nWeapon
298,NULL,6,1,Select\nWeapon
299,NULL,6,1,Select\nWeapon
385,NULL,7,1,NULL
386,NULL,7,1,NULL
387,NULL,7,1,NULL
388,NULL,7,1,NULL
621,NULL,8,1,"Toggle\nFree Look"
622,NULL,8,1,Select\nAll
623,NULL,8,1,Select\nArchers
624,NULL,8,1,Select\nInfantry
695,NULL,9,1,Bioscan
696,NULL,9,1,Fullscreen\nView
697,NULL,9,1,Sense\n-Around
```

and a "records" table like this:

```
record_id,game_id,layout_id,author_id
8,3,1,1
9,4,1,1
10,5,1,1
11,6,1,1
12,7,1,1
13,8,1,1
14,9,1,1
```

How do I feed the "record_id" values in the "records" table back into the "bindings" table where "game_id" and "layout_id" in both tables are the same?

Thanks!

[edit]

I'll try again, if it's not clear. I need to feed the values for "record_id" from the "records" table into the "bindings" table where "game_id" and "layout_id" are both the same in both tables. The other columns are not really relevant since they don't need to be changed.

"record_id" is the primary key in the "records" table, and a foreign key in the "bindings" table.

Afterward I am going to delete the "game_id" and "layout_id" columns in the bindings table since they will no longer be necessary.

[edit]

I thought of trying something like this:

```
SELECT b.binding_id,r.record_id,b.key_number,b.normal_action
INTO newtable
FROM bindings as b, records as r
where b.game_id = r.game_id and b.layout_id = r.layout_id;
```

MySQL complains about "newtable" being undeclared, however.

Comment: At your rep level, I would expect a question which at least includes a minimal sample of the data from both tables, directly included in the question.  We shouldn't have to use those links, which might break later on anyway.

Comment: Okay I added the records.

Comment: Please also tell us how the columns map.  Note that there is no `author_id` in the first table.

Comment: I don't understand. Eventually the goal is to remove "game_id" and "layout_id" from table #1 and replace them with just the foreign key "record_id". In table #2 "record_id" is the primary key.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a join to create a *new* table with the information I wanted. Then, I substituted the new table for the old table.

```
CREATE TABLE `bindings_copy` (
  `binding_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `game_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `layout_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key_number` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `normal_action` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `normal_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift_action` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctrl_action` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctrl_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_action` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `altgr_action` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `altgr_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_action` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_group` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_file` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`binding_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `binding_id_UNIQUE` (`binding_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16460 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
SELECT
    bindings.binding_id,
    records.record_id,
    bindings.game_id,
    bindings.layout_id,
    bindings.key_number,
    bindings.normal_action,
    bindings.normal_group,
    bindings.shift_action,
    bindings.shift_group,
    bindings.ctrl_action,
    bindings.ctrl_group,
    bindings.alt_action,
    bindings.alt_group,
    bindings.altgr_action,
    bindings.altgr_group,
    bindings.extra_action,
    bindings.extra_group,
    bindings.image_file
FROM bindings
left JOIN records
ON bindings.game_id=records.game_id and bindings.layout_id=records.layout_id;
```